# How to forbidden return comments with status unseen?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I write query for get comments and reply commants for post.
Comments and reply comments put on comments table.
My query is:

```
$comments = Comment::with(['reply_comments', 'user', 'scores'])
            ->where('comments.place_id', $place[0]->id)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Although in where condition check status of comments, this condition done on comments but don't on replyComment.
That's mean return reply comment when status is unseen.
How to change query or condition for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter relationships as well in the `with`:

```
$comments = Comment::with(['reply_comments' => function ($query) {
          $query->where('status', 1);
        }, 'user', 'scores'])
        ->where('comments.place_id', $place[0]->id)
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();
```